# Getting same element from a tuple and returning two indexed lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have the list below (in fact it's longer but it's just to give the idea):

```
[[('P', 0.3178082191780822, 1750.0, 12.5),
  ('C', 0.8191780821917808, 1800.0, 332.80000000000001),
  ('P', 0.3178082191780822, 1325.0, 1.95),
  ('P', 0.14520547945205478, 1550.0, 1.0),
  ('C', 1.8136986301369864, 1900.0, 305.56999999999999),
  ('P', 0.3178082191780822, 1700.0, 9.9000000000000004),
  ('P', 0.14520547945205478, 2010.0, 18.949999999999999)]]
```

where each tuple refers to (option_type, time_to_maturity, strike, option_price).

I have to perform a double integration over the time_to_maturity and the strikes, so I would select for each different time_to_maturity (the second element of each tuple) the corresponding strike value (the third element of each tuples). What I would obtain is a list containing the time to maturity and another list containing the tuple of strikes which corresponds to the single time to maturity (a time to maturity is associated to different strikes, but generally the opposite does not hold). Is there a way to do that?

**EDIT**
This is one of the 10 list in which I would remove the tuples with 'P' that have the same strike of consecutive tuples with 'C':

(0.8328767123287671, [('P', 1200.0, 7.75), ('P', 1300.0, 11.199999999999999), ('P', 1400.0, 15.5), ('P', 1500.0, 21.600000000000001), ('C', 1500.0, 590.14999999999998), ('P', 1550.0, 24.75), ('P', 1575.0, 26.0), ('C', 1575.0, 522.0), ('P', 1600.0, 29.100000000000001), ('P', 1650.0, 33.5), ('P', 1675.0, 35.899999999999999), ('P', 1700.0, 39.700000000000003), ('P', 1725.0, 42.600000000000001), ('P', 1800.0, 53.0), ('P', 1850.0, 62.100000000000001), ('P', 1875.0, 67.5), ('P', 1900.0, 72.700000000000003), ('C', 1900.0, 243.09999999999999), ('P', 1950.0, 84.900000000000006), ('C', 1975.0, 189.30000000000001), ('P', 2000.0, 98.0), ('C', 2000.0, 171.0), ('C', 2050.0, 139.09999999999999), ('C', 2075.0, 122.59999999999999), ('P', 2075.0, 126.0), ('C', 2100.0, 108.0), ('P', 2100.0, 133.0), ('C', 2150.0, 81.400000000000006), ('C', 2200.0, 57.700000000000003), ('C', 2250.0, 39.0), ('P', 2250.0, 217.59999999999999), ('C', 2300.0, 24.350000000000001), ('P', 2300.0, 253.40000000000001), ('C', 2350.0, 14.35), ('C', 2375.0, 11.0), ('C', 2400.0, 8.0), ('C', 2500.0, 2.5499999999999998), ('P', 2500.0, 427.85000000000002)])

Comment: The double brackets suggest you have a list of a list of tuples. Is that a typo?

Comment: No, it is like that. If it is a problem I can modify it using zip(*option_data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to group your records by `time_to_maturity`, so why not use `itertools.groupby`? This requires you to sort but to be able to integrate you have to sort anyway, so I guess that's ok.

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

data, = [[('P', 0.3178082191780822, 1750.0, 12.5),
          ('C', 0.8191780821917808, 1800.0, 332.80000000000001),
          ('P', 0.3178082191780822, 1325.0, 1.95),
          ('P', 0.14520547945205478, 1550.0, 1.0),
          ('C', 1.8136986301369864, 1900.0, 305.56999999999999),
          ('P', 0.3178082191780822, 1700.0, 9.9000000000000004),
          ('P', 0.14520547945205478, 2010.0, 18.949999999999999)]]

# sort records ignoring 0th column
ds = sorted(data, key=op.itemgetter(slice(1, None)))
# group by 1st column
gr = it.groupby(ds, op.itemgetter(1))
# cut the first two entries from each record in each group
# the 1st entry is redundant with key, and the 0th I don't know what
# it's good for. To retain it use vi[:1] + vi[2:] instead of just vi[2:]
gr = [(k, [vi[2:] for vi in v]) for k, v in gr]
print(gr)
```

Prints:

```
[(0.14520547945205478, [(1550.0, 1.0), (2010.0, 18.95)]), (0.3178082191780822, [(1325.0, 1.95), (1700.0, 9.9), (1750.0, 12.5)]), (0.8191780821917808, [(1800.0, 332.8)]), (1.8136986301369864, [(1900.0, 305.57)])]
```

Note that as it stands this drops the 'P'/'C' column. But this can be easily remedied should you require to retain it, see comment in code.

Comment: It works perfectly. That's exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!

Comment: What if I would improve the code you wrote not including certain tuples with 'P' element?  I applied your code to the long list I have and it works perfectly. By the way I would not include in the list gr some tuples that have 'P' as first entry and the strike (the second entry) equal to another tuple with 'C'. Do you think it is possible to do that directly from the last line of code you wrote?

Comment: Same strike _and_ time_to_maturity or only same strike?

Comment: You're right, same strike and same ttm. In the list posted above there is no example of such case but my longer list is full of them.

Comment: But there are at most two with same strike and ttm (one with P one with C)?

Comment: More than just one pairs. I edited the questions to show you one of the lists that contain such pair. I would delete them from every list grouped by time to maturity.

Comment: What I meant was for a given ttm and strike there can be only one P and only one C, so there are no triplets or quadruplets etc. Anyway, since we sorted, such pairs will sit next to each other. You can just go through the groups and look for consecutive records with the same strike. Give it a try, if you can't manage I'll have another look.

Comment: Yes, exactly...there are at most two with same strike and ttm. BY the way, thank to your code I know that they sit next to each other and I tried to select them using two nested for loops under an if condition. I was wondering if it is possible to do it directly from using list comprehension because the two nested loops don't work well and they raise and index error. If you want I can edit and put also this code on the initial post.

Comment: Ok I've written you a one-liner. It's pretty much unreadable, but it seems to work: `gr = [(k, map(op.itemgetter(0, 2, 3), map(min, (igr for ik, igr in it.groupby(v, op.itemgetter(2)))))) for k, v in gr]` What we are doing is just throwing another groupby at each group found by the first groupby. The groups found either one or two elements large. Taking the min selects the only element in the first case and the one having a 'C' in the first place in the second case.

Comment: It raises an error 'IndexError: tuple index out of range'. I really don't know how to solve it

Comment: Are you using it on the original data or those where ttm has already been removed from the records?

Comment: I was using on data without ttm...if I use it on original data I obtain exactly what I want. I don't know how to thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to extract a dimension:

```
time_to_maturity_list = [time_to_maturity for option_type, time_to_maturity, strike, option_price in my_list]
strikes_list = [strike for option_type, time_to_maturity, strike, option_price in my_list]
```

This is very readable but it does mean looping over the list twice. An alternative is to create two lists and append the items as you do a normal for loop:

```
time_to_maturity_list = []
strike_list = []
for option_type, time_to_maturity, strike, option_price in my_list:
    time_to_maturity_list.append(time_to_maturity)
    strike_list.append(strike)
```

NOTE: my_list is just a single list [tuple, tuple] either take the first element of your data or do something to concatenate all of the lists (like a nested for loop)